# AJAX call in wordpress template

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I got a problem with getting my working php/javascript/ajax application into my wordpress theme. I use it for my users so not in the admin panel.

**What I already did:**
I called the JavaScript file in my functions.php. And its loading fine. But when I open my main php file it doesn't make the ajax call.

I have 4 pages: response.php

- response.php (This one is working fine.)
- single-page.php (This one is also working fine.)
- voedingsschema.js (This one is working without wordpress.)
- function.php (I don't know if I did this right.)

I hope I've given enough information.

The function.php code from my template looks like this:

```php
function fitnesszone_child_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'voedingsschema js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/voedingsschema.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fitnesszone_child_scripts');
```

The javascript code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //##### send add record Ajax request to response.php #########
    $("#FormSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if($("#contentText").val()==='')
            {
                alert("Please enter some text!");
                return false;
            }

            $("#FormSubmit").hide(); //hide submit button
            $("#LoadingImage").show(); //show loading image



            var myData = {
            content_txt: $('#contentText').val(),
            content_txt2: $('#contentText2').val(),
            };
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "http://website.com/wp-content/themes/fitnesszone-child/response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                $("#responds").append(response);
                $("#contentText").val(''); //empty text field on successful
                $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
                $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image

            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
                $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
    });

    //##### Send delete Ajax request to response.php #########
    $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split ID string (Split works as PHP explode)
         var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
         var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure

        $('#item_'+DbNumberID).addClass( "sel" ); //change background of this element by adding class
        $(this).hide(); //hide currently clicked delete button

            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
            url: "http://website.com/wp-content/themes/fitnesszone-child/response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
            dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
            data:myData, //Form variables
            success:function(response){
                //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut();
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                //On error, we alert user
                alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, the function.php file looks like this.[code]<?php

function fitnesszone_child_scripts(){
 wp_enqueue_script( 'voedingsschema js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/voedingsschema.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fitnesszone_child_scripts');
?>[/code]

Comment: Is there an error in your console?

Comment: No there is no error. :(

Comment: So that means javascript does nothing, no error and no execution of your code. Can you maybe add the code from your functions.php, your example above is empty ;)

Comment: The code is added. If i go to my single-page.php, I see my javascript is loading google chrome.

Comment: I cant see a problem within your code, do you have a live example or a jsfiddle for me to look at?

Comment: I have a live example here: http://tinyurl.com/htj7z9a. Don't look at the stylesheet atm.

Comment: This explains alot, when using chrome press f12. You will see alot of errors. First of all try to remove your script tag within your voedingsschema.js. Since it's a .js file you don't need a script tag in the file

Comment: Second thing, replace `$(document).ready(function() {` with `jQuery(function($){` Wordpress doesnt know the $ dollar function so you nede to tell that jQuery is $

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I did ur changes and it helped already, but u gave me a step in the right direction.

Comment: Alright good luck, just one little thing. Remove the javascript code in your index. Now your ajax call is added twice to the same page. This will execute it twice or just not work at all. Have fun with your project ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this way for implementing ajax in WordPress

**functions.php**

```
function fitnesszone_child_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'voedingsschema_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/voedingsschema.js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'voedingsschema_js', 'voedingsschema_vars', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fitnesszone_child_scripts' );

function fitnesszone_implement_ajax(){
    include( TEMPLATEPATH .'/response.php');
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fitnesszone', 'fitnesszone_implement_ajax' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fitnesszone', 'fitnesszone_implement_ajax' );
```

**voedingsschema.js**

```
var contentTxt: $('#contentText').val();
var contentTxt2: $('#contentText2').val();

$.ajax({
    url: voedingsschema_vars.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'action=fitnesszone&context_txt=contextTxt&context_txt2=contextTxt2,
    success: function(results){
        // YOUR CODE
    },
});
```

Don't wrap javascript code in voedingsschema.js into `<script></script>` tag. This is reserved when you put javascript code inside your HTML

Comment: I tried this. It looks like it still not connecting with the function.php page. The ajax script is getting called. Thanks for the help already!

Comment: Pay attention, the function file in WordPress is called **functions.php**!